# Not an instance of a class Vectors java

Tags: java, vector, syntax-error, instanceof

I would like to know how to check if an element in a vector is not an instance of a class.
The scenario is if the element in vector m exists in a class we increment sum. If `i` is not an instance of the class then we return -1. Here is my code:

```
public static int CountHighs(Vector m) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        try {
            if (m.get(i) instanceof HighRights) {
                sum += 1;
            } else if ((!m.get(i) instanceof Highrights) || (!m.get(i) instanceof LowRights)) {
                sum = -1;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException E) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I have used the operator "!" here for the respondents benefit.

The `!m.gets` causes an error. I was wondering if there was a way of stating if element is not an instance of this class.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik The !m.gets causes me an error, I was wondering if there was a way of stating if element is not an instance of this class.  Apologies for the ambiguity

Comment: `catch(NullPointerException E)` What? And that block doesn't even do something usefull.

Comment: @duldi What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mureinik I get a "bad operand type java.lang.Object for unary operator "!"

Comment: Have you ever thought about using parentheses? Like `!(m.get(i) instanceof Highrights))` ...

Comment: @Tom Thank you that helped I feel foolish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unary operators (such as `!`) have a higher precedence than relational operators (such as `instanceof`) in Java (see [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for details). So Java tries to interpret `!m.get(i)` first and fails, since `m.get(i)` does not return a boolean. In order to solve this issue, you should use parentheses to make the `instanceof` evaluate first:

```
else if (!((m.get(i) instanceof Highrights) || (m.get(i) instanceof LowRights))) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering why it made such a difference, thank you for your help

Comment: oops this is wrong !(A || B) => !A && !B which is not what OP wants

Comment: Like Nicolas mentioned, you need to use `&&` instead of `||`, when you extract the negation from the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this `(!m.get(i) instanceof Highrights)` for this `!(m.get(i) instanceof Highrights)`. Indeed `!` is an operator for `boolean` values but here `m.get(i)` doesn't return a `boolean` but an object so it doesn't compile, so you need to put it outside your parentesis to get the negative value of your test `x instanceof y`.

So the test at the end is `!(m.get(i) instanceof Highrights) || !(m.get(i) instanceof LowRights)`

**NB:** Here your test is in an `else if` which means that the previous `if` failed so you know already that `m.get(i) instanceof HighRights` is `false` such that your test will `!(m.get(i) instanceof Highrights) || !(m.get(i) instanceof LowRights)` will always be `true` so I believe that your test should be only `else if (!(m.get(i) instanceof LowRights))`

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
else if(!(m.get(i) instanceof LowRights))
```

I also formatted the rest of your code, and took out the unnecessary check:

```
else if(!(m.get(i) instanceof Highrights))
```

The parenthesis will treat the entire statement as a `boolean` and then you you can negate that with a `!`. Also since you use an `else if` it means that `m.get(i)` can't be and instance of `HighRights` so the check is unnecessary so your final code would look like:

```
public static int CountHighs (Vector m) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<m.size();i++){   
        try{
            if(m.get(i) instanceof HighRights){   
            sum+=1;
        }
        else if(!(m.get(i) instanceof LowRights)){   
            sum=-1;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException E){
            System.out.println("Error");
            System.exit(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```